# What is constant and variable error

Tags: error, variable

What is constant error (CE) and variable error (VE)? I’ve seen the terms in several papers.

Comment: could you provide their formulas, or link to where they appear

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more context? Which research papers have you seen it in?

For this explanation, I am assuming you are talking about Measurement Errors and breaking them down to systemic error vs variable error as in this article https://sciencing.com/constant-error-12216420.html

In Statistics and Survey design, they are usually referred to as Bias and Variable Error (an in some contexts as Variance). Bias is an error that is the same in repeated measurements while variable error isn't. You may also refer to this video https://www.coursera.org/lecture/data-collection-methods/1-2-2-variable-error-and-bias-l2p9O

A statistical estimate based on a survey or sample tries to estimate the true value of a parameter. The true value could be known or unknown. If there is a deficiency in our methodology including data collection, the Expected Value (or mean) of repeated samples would be the same. The difference of this Expected Value from True Value is the Bias. The sample variance will give you the variable error.

For example, you want to estimate what % of online news readers are interested in sports content and conduct an online survey of visitors to a sports website. The % of visitors saying that they are interested (say 80%) may be expected to be higher than all readers of online news (say 50%). This difference is the Bias. Now if you repeat the survey every day, the results may vary from 75% to 85%. This part is the variable error.

Comment: Here are the links of the articles. 

http://www.bbk.ac.uk/psychology/bodylab/docs/manciniEtal-neuropsychologia-2011.pdf

https://kar.kent.ac.uk/71612/1/Medina%20et%20al%202018_EBR_Final.pdf

Comment: Based on the links you've shared, my answer is correct though the context is different. Here systemic error, bias and constant error are synonymous while variable error is synonymous with precision and variance. Though I don't have a medical or bio background, apparently the precision or variable error in the first link is the error the same person would make while repetitively locating a sensation on the skin. Compared to say after taking drugs that might affect such ability to locate skin sensations - which would be the bias or constant error... constant after taking the drug.

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, you have error that shrinks the more data you collect (or disappears if you have infinite data) and error that remains independent of how much data you collect. The first is called **random error** or variable error in your case. The second one is called **systematic error** or constant error in your case.

For example, let's say I want to know the average height of men and women in a classroom. I can pick only *a few* men and women at random, and use their (sample) average height to infer about the classroom average height. This is random error—if I pick the whole classroom I will have no zero random error.

Now imagine that I am not actually measuring them but just asking them to *self-report* height. Assume that men will inflate their self-reported height. This error will remain even if I ask the whole classroom. We will be extremely precisely wrong.

As you see, systematic errors (usually called biases) are huge validity threats to our inferences. Yet most of the efforts to account for error will restrict themselves only to sampling error. For random error we can estimate our precision (e.g. by means of confidence intervals). For most systematic errors or biases, we have not even a guess about their magnitude or direction. Thus, sensitivity or bias analyses are an essential part of research.

---

*Further reading:*

Greenland, S., & Rafi, Z. (2019). To aid scientific inference, emphasize unconditional descriptions of statistics. arXiv preprint arXiv:1909.08583.

Greenland, S. (2005). Multiple-bias modeling for observational studies (with discussion). Journal of the Royal Statistical Society, Series A, 168, 267-306.